# How do I modify VirtualDisplay returned by DisplayManager.createVirtualDisplay() method?

Tags: java, android

The [Displaymanager.createVirtualDisplay()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.html#createVirtualDisplay(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.Surface,%20int,%20android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay.Callback,%20android.os.Handler)) method returns a VirtualDisplay object and it says it will render the content of the virtual display to the given Surface. But how do I modify the content of that virtual display?

My ultimate goal is to modify the content of the virtual display and render it to the inputSurface created by [MediaCodec.createInputSurface()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#createInputSurface()).

Comment: what do you want by modifying the virtual display?

Comment: @Md.Sulayman I want to modify the content of the virtual display so I can render it to the inputSurface created by MediaCodec.createInputSurface()